# Github authentication auto-failing

Tags: git, github, git-bash

As it says, moment I try to connect to a github repo it just straight up fails, doesn't ask for authentication, just dies right away and gives "fatal authentication" error. Is previous authentication saved somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, when using Git Bash integrated in VScode, it tracks credentials in Windows Credential Manager, deleting the saved credentials will bring up the prompt again

Comment: It would be great to include the steps to update the windows credential manager, for future readers.